# why the reset event not updating the state

Tags: reactjs

here method handleReset() to reset the each values of counter state to zero. But state is not getting updated.
why it is so?

```
  state={
    counters:[
      {id:1,value:3},
      {id:2,value:7},
      {id:3,value:6}
    ]
   }
  

  handleReset = () => {
        const counters = this.state.counters.map(c => {
            c.value = 0
            return c
        })
        console.log(counters.value)
        this.setState({ counters })
    }
```

The log shows the values as zero.but the state still shows the original values

Comment: since `counters` is an array then what you are expecting from `console.log(counters.value)`?

Comment: And how do you know the state is not getting updated?

Comment: I cant see in FE.when i click on the given button <button onClick={this.handleReset}> Reset</button>

Comment: post your FE code

Answer (score 0):

`this.setState()` is an asynchronous function, it will not update the state immediately. If you want to see the changes after updating state you can pass callback function as follows.

```
handleReset = () => {
        const counters = this.state.counters.map(c => {
            c.value = 0
            return c
        })
        console.log(counters.value)
        this.setState({ counters },()=>console.log(this.state))
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try  below code

```
this.setState(() => ({ counters }))
```

Answer (score 0):

you did not set the value counters  in setState You must set the counters  equal to the counters

```
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    
  
    
    class App extends React.PureComponent {
       constructor(props){
         super(props);
         this.state={
        counters:[
          {id:1,value:3},
          {id:2,value:7},
          {id:3,value:6}
        ]
       }
    
       this.handleReset = this.handleReset.bind(this);
       }
    
        handleReset = () => {
            const counters = this.state.counters.map(c => {
                c.value = 0
                return c
            })
           
            this.setState({ counters:counters })
 console.log("counters1",this.state.counters)
        }
        render() {
           console.log("counters",this.state.counters)
          
            return (
               <div>
            <button onClick={this.handleReset}> Reset</button>
               </div>
            );
        }
    
     
    }
    
    ReactDOM.render(
        <App />,
        document.querySelector('my-app')
```